# How do I set the same width for all tabs in PagerSlidingTabStrip for Android?

Tags: android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I want each tab to have the same width as my widest tab in the PagerSlidingTabStrip.  I still want the tabs to extend beyond the screen width so that they are scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Samples from the developers site SlidingTabsBasic. Then you can set width of the textview in the method(under the SlidingTabLayout class).

```
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context)
```